# Magento2 messages is not getting added & not getting displayed

Tags: magento2, compare

Magento2 error message is not getting displayed, it gets displayed only after page refresh. I checked in console, the error msg is not getting added in messages:

```
  public function aroundExecute(
    \Magento\Catalog\Controller\Product\Compare\Add $subject,
    \Closure $proceed
    ){

      $count = $this->helper->getItemCount();
      if($count >= self::LIMIT_TO_COMPARE_PRODUCTS) {
        $this->messageManager->addError(
            'You can add the compared products under 3 item(s)'
        );

        /** @var \Magento\Framework\Controller\Result\Redirect $resultRedirect */
        $resultRedirect = $this->resultRedirectFactory->create();
        return $resultRedirect->setRefererOrBaseUrl();
      }

      return $proceed();
   }
```

Comment: Are you using the ajax to process the request?

Comment: yes I guess, as I m using default add to compare

Comment: I don't think, because in default magento add to compare does not work on ajax. Check here https://magento.nublue.co.uk/gear/bags.html

Comment: I was just checking I think it is because I am returning message via plugin so might be it is not working